# @Html.DropDownList selected value issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I do submit I get StateID is always empty.

Any clue what do I am missing here?

THANK YOU!

HTML:

```
<div style="display: inline-block;">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Common.StateID , new { @class = "SmallInput2" })</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;">@Html.DropDownList("StateID", Model.Common.StateList, "-- Select --",  new { style = "width: 130px;" })</div>
```

Code:

```
public ActionResult SignUp()
        {
            var model =  new SignUpModel
            {
                Common = new Common(),
                Individual = new Individual(),
                Business = new Business()
            };

            var stateList = new SelectList(_context.States.OrderBy(w => w.StateName), "ID", "StateName", _context.States.OrderBy(w => w.StateName).FirstOrDefault().ID);
            model.Common.StateList = stateList;
            model.Common.StateID = _context.States.OrderBy(w => w.StateName).FirstOrDefault().ID;

            return View(model);
        }
```

Model:

```
[Display(Name = "State")]
public Guid StateID { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "States")]
public SelectList StateList { get; set; }
```

Comment: And do you get other properties of the model set as expected?

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov Yes I do. All other proprieties are correct.

Comment: I think it could be connected with the name `StateId`...I guess it would be different if you used `DropDownListFor`. So, the binder failed to bind it...it should have some prefix...Check the generated html for other properties. If you used the `..EditorFor` helper methods, you would see it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found correct solution here [@Html.DropDownList selected value issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378151/html-dropdownlist-selected-value-issue/13378314#13378314)

So in my case it should be like:

```
   <div style="display: inline-block;">@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Common.StateID, Model.Common.StateList, "-- Select --",  new { style = "width: 130px;" })</div>
```